# Verify archlinux signature

Tags: arch-linux

How am i able to verify my archlinux iso?

```
gpg --verify archlinux-2020.06.01-x86_64.iso.sig archlinux-2020.06.01-x86_64.iso
gpg: Signature made Mo 01 Jun 2020 11:53:53 CEST
gpg:                using RSA key 4AA4767BBC9C4B1D18AE28B77F2D434B9741E8AC
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

I am missing the public key, but where exactly am i able to download it. Also there is a sha1, but what should i do with it?

Comment: Does it [answer your question](https://www.linuxbabe.com/security/verify-pgp-signature-software-downloads-linux) ? Alternatively, you can check the RSA Key with the [official website](https://www.archlinux.org/download/) where you could have found [that link](https://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?op=vindex&fingerprint=on&exact=on&search=0x4AA4767BBC9C4B1D18AE28B77F2D434B9741E8AC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checksums are meant to be used with the `-c` ("check") option of the corresponding program, running it from the directory to which you downloaded the ISO/archive files and the `*sums.txt` file:

```
$ sha1sum -c sha1sums.txt 
archlinux-2020.06.01-x86_64.iso: OK
```

(Error messages about missing files (which I didn't download) omitted for clarity).

Instructions on how to verify the signature of downloaded files can be found in the [installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Verify_signature), part of the Arch Wiki:

```
$ gpg --keyserver-options auto-key-retrieve --verify archlinux-2020.06.01-x86_64.iso.sig
```

If you are not running this on a working Arch Linux system, your `gpg` may be unable to retrieve the needed key from the keyservers it knows about. You may then try adding `--keyserver=hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net` to your command (URL picked from pacman's configuration of a currently working Arch).

If, instead, you already have a working Arch, you also have the public keys you need—just not in your own keyring:

```
$ gpg --homedir=/etc/pacman.d/gnupg --verify archlinux-2020.06.01-x86_64.iso.sig
```

Comment: gpg --keyserver-options auto-key-retrieve --verify archlinux-2020.06.01-x86_64.iso.sig
did not work with ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Did you get some error messages? Does `gpg --search-keys pierre@archlinux.de` return "key not found on keyserver"?

Comment: gpg: data source: https://keys.openpgp.org:443
gpg: key "pierre@archlinux.de" not found on keyserver
gpg: keyserver search failed: Not found

Comment: Try `gpg --recv-keys --keyserver=hkp://keys.gnupg.net 7F2D434B9741E8AC` (I see it works on Debian, no Ubuntu at hand right now). Unfortunately I couldn't comment on the availability of Arch people's keys on keyservers.

Answer (score 1):

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and I had this same issue, what I did to solve it was I got the public key (someone please correct me if I did something wrong):

```
curl https://git.archlinux.org/archlinux-keyring.git/plain/packager/pierre.asc > archpub.key
```

then I imported this public key into my gpg keyring (I think):

```
gpg --import archpub.key
```

then I was able to verify the signature (with the .iso and the .sig files in the same directory):

```
gpg --verify archlinux-2021.05.01-x86_64.iso.sig
```

and here is what that command printed back:

```
gpg: assuming signed data in 'archlinux-2021.05.01-x86_64.iso'
gpg: Signature made Sat 01 May 2021 01:24:14 AM EDT
gpg:                using RSA key 4AA4767BBC9C4B1D18AE28B77F2D434B9741E8AC
gpg: Good signature from "Pierre Schmitz <pierre@archlinux.de>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 4AA4 767B BC9C 4B1D 18AE  28B7 7F2D 434B 9741 E8AC
```

Hopefully this helps someone!  I tried to import the public key using `--keyserver=hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net` but for some reason it didn't work for me.

Comment: Similarly, one could grab a key from the [Arch Linux Developers](https://archlinux.org/people/developers) page (possibly easier to remember).